# How to manage session of a user in all tabs of browser in SignalR?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

Hello guys I am new to SignalR, going to develop a web application like chat messaging. How can i manage session of a user in all tabs of browser?
Thanks in adv.

Comment: Browsers have a limitation of the maximum number of connections to the same host address (same application).
So, this limits the maximum number of opened browser windows of the same application with SignalR connections. Try IWC-SignalR js can solve your problem. https://github.com/slimjack/IWC

Comment: Is the user logged in? If so the simplest solution is to assert that the user can only be logged in once then you can use User to map to a session. A more complicated way I've done it is using the UserData  string in the FormsAuthentication cookie to store a sessionId - that is retrievable in both MVC and SignalR